# Output Users collection nodejs

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

**edit 1**

user model and schema code

```
const express = require('express');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

var app = express();

if (app.get('env') === 'production') {
  mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, { useMongoClient: true });
} else {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/pol-development', { useMongoClient: true });
}

var db = mongoose.connection;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
  console.log("Connection has been established");
});

var UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  schoolName: String,
  schoolAddress: String,
  schoolAddress2: String,
  city: String,
  zipCode: String,
  addressCheck: Boolean,
  postalAddress: String,
  postalCity: String,
  postalZipCode: String,
  telephone: String,
  fax: String,
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: String,
  schoolType: String,
  schoolDistrict: String,
  schoolRegion: String,
  curriculum: String,
  participationBefore: Boolean,
  participationYears: String,
  directorName: String,
  directorTelephone: String,
  directorEmail: String,
  directorAttendanceRehersal: Boolean,
  directorAttendanceEvent: Boolean,
  schoolRepresentativeName: String,
  schoolRepresentativeTelephone: String,
  schoolRepresentativeEmail: String,
  schoolRepresentativePosition: String,
  schoolRepresentativeOtherPosition: String,
  schoolRepresentativeTShirt: String,
  schoolRepresentativeTutorMentor: String,
  admin: { type: Boolean, default: false },

  // admin fields
  directorAttendanceRehersal: Boolean,
  directorCompetitionEvent: Boolean,
  attendanceRehersal: Boolean,
  attendanceEvent: Boolean,
});

var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);

module.exports.createUser = function(newUser, callback){
  bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
    bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, function(err, hash) {
      newUser.password = hash;
      newUser.save(callback);
    });
  });
}

module.exports.getUserByEmail = function(email, callback){
  var query = {email: email};
  User.findOne(query, callback);
}

module.exports.getUserById = function(id, callback){
  User.findById(id, callback);
}

module.exports.comparePassword = function(candidatePassword, hash, callback) {
  bcrypt.compare(candidatePassword, hash, function(err, isMatch) {
    if(err) throw err;
    callback(null, isMatch);
  });
}

// get all users from collection
db.collection("users").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log(result);
  db.close();
});
```

**original**

I have my UsersSchema and I have a users collection but I want to loop and output all users.

Currently I have

```
{{#each user}}
  <tr>
    <td><a href="/dashboard/users/{{_id}}">{{schoolName}}</a></td>
    <td>{{city}}</td>
    <td>{{email}}</td>
    <td>{{schoolRepresentativeName}}</td>
    <td>{{schoolRepresentativeTutorMentor}}</td>
  </tr>
{{/each}}
```

But only the user you are signed in is being outputted.

Here is what is appearing in the view

[image]

the route is currently like so

```
router.get('/dashboard/users', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  res.render('dashboard/users/index.hbs', {
    pageTitle: 'Users'
  });
});
```

how do I output all users in the collection?

Comment: you have to use mongodb or mongoose query to get all docs from db

Answer (score 0):

Have you trying using the **MongoDB** query called `db.collection.find()` which allows you to locate all the elements of a collection? [db.collection.find()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/)

**EDIT 1** This didn't work in the first place because you weren't actually querying your **MongoDB Schema** but you were just pasting my example code.

I can see that you have actually defined your schema as `var UserSchema` so replace that in my code, resulting in:

```
dbo.collection("UserSchema").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
    db.close();
  });
```

Now the question is how will you capture this query, you need to display it on the html page. Watching the `console log` in the query => `console.log(result);` you should be able to see all the user information being logged in your command prompt. Did this work for you?

[MongoDB with NodeJS Examples.](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_find.asp)

Comment: So I tried the above code, now I'm getting https://gyazo.com/29b5d4ea1e29c74592da514db126529d

Comment: @B.J.B you need a MongoDB or a Mongoose schema to be defined, such as `users`. Afterwards you need to query it. Please paste your full `NodeJS` code so that I can actually help you solve your problem.

Comment: @ ZombieChowder Any thoughts?

Comment: @B.J.B I've added something, I hope that helps. You are missing some code to actually capture the query and display it on the HTML but that is a discussion for a whole other question of you ask me. Did it help? If not what output do you get and I will try to fix it again.